# JavaScript requesting JSON info. returns incorrect result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm quite new to JavaScript and keep having problems with importing JSONs. I'm making something similar to the alarm seen in iron man, with Jarvis greeting the person. When I try to import the weather through the OpenWeatherMap API, I get random results like a temperature of 0... I just need to define 4 variables, one with the temperature, one with the wind speed, one with the general description `(data.weather.main)`, and one with the humidity. If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, and/or show me an example of how to do it for one of the variables, I would be grateful. Thanks in advance

JSON:

```
{ "coord": { "lon": -71.37, "lat": 42.24 }, "weather": [{ "id": 802, "main": "Clouds", "description": "scattered clouds", "icon": "03n" }], "base": "stations", "main": { "temp": 63.55, "pressure": 1014, "humidity": 77, "temp_min": 62.6, "temp_max": 66.2 }, "visibility": 16093, "wind": { "speed": 4.7, "deg": 80 }, "clouds": { "all": 40 }, "dt": 1500871860, "sys": { "type": 1, "id": 2390, "message": 0.0161, "country": "US", "sunrise": 1500888653, "sunset": 1500941553 }, "id": 4950790, "name": "Sherborn", "cod": 200 }
```

CODE:

```
<html>
<title>Good Morning</title>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
    <script>
        /*
                function setup() {
                $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={Sherborn}&APPID=355c20fb396a58c1c25e0c341c9035ed&units=imperial', function(Data) {
               console.log (Data.weather.main);
                if (Data.weather.main = 'Clouds') {
                window.WeatherStatus = "Cloudy"
                }})} */
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={Sherborn}&APPID=355c20fb396a58c1c25e0c341c9035ed&units=imperial',
            datatype: 'json',
            type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            success: function(Data) {
                $(Data.main).each(function(temp, wind) {
                    console.log(temp);
                    console.log(wind)
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The data is returning fine and JSON is correct.  You need to parse out the value you need correctly.  Look at Data.main.temp and Data.wind.speed after you've received the result.

Comment: surely you can post 33 lines of code **in the question** (as required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your return success to this:

```
success: function(Data) {
          console.log(Data.weather[0].main);//show weather
          console.log(Data.main.temp);//show temp
          console.log(Data.main.humidity);//show humidity
          console.log(Data.wind.speed);//show speed
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After AJAX returns success do

```
console.log(Data.main.temp);
```

//and

```
console.log(Data.wind.speed);
```

you should see correct values